# Python lambdas in Jinja2

Tags: python, templates, lambda, jinja2

I use Jinja2 as a website template engine, and all helper functions used in templates I've implemented as macros, but for one. This is it's Python code:

```
def arrow_class_from_deg(angle):
    if angle is None:
        return ''
    arrow_directions = [
        (0, 'n'), (45, 'ne'), (90, 'e'), (135, 'se'), (180, 's'),
        (225, 'sw'), (270, 'w'), (315, 'nw'), (360, 'n')
    ]
    return min(arrow_directions, key=lambda (ang, _): abs(ang - angle))[1]
```

It returns CSS class for an arrow, which is closest to the specified angle. This function is (and will be) used only in templates, so it makes sense to implement in in templates too, namely as a macro. However, trying to do this I noticed that Jinja2 doesn't seem to support Python lambdas. Is it true, and if yes then how to write this function better (I hope loop isn't necessary here)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

register it as a filter:

```
your_jinja_env.filters['arrow_class'] = arrow_class_from_deg
```

and in template:

```
<something class="{{ angle | arrow_class }}">blah</something>
```

you can use decorators to manage jinja filters easily:

```
class Filter(object):
    def __init__(self, filter_name=None):
         self.filter_name = filter_name

    def __call__(self, function):
         my_jinja_env.filters[self.filter_name or function.__name__] = function
         return function

@Filter()
def i_love_you(name):
    ''' say I love you to the name you entered. 
    usage: {{ "John" | i_love_you }} => "I Love You, John!"'''

    return "I Love You, %s!" %name
```

Comment: So, it is impossible to implement in templates?